# Loading WFS via QuickImport from ArcGIS Data InteroperabilityTools

Tags: arcobjects, wfs, file-geodatabase, geoprocessing-framework

For a project I have to load a WFS layer in ArcMap programmatically. Since Version 10.0 there is no ability to use the FMEWorkspace as discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10654/arcmap-addin-add-interoperability-connection-programatically).

The only way to load WFS-Data to ArcMap is to use `QuickImport` from `ESRI.ArcGIS.DataInteroperabilityTools`. If someone knows another trick, please tell!

Now I have a problem in consuming the geoprocessing-tool. As input I give the content of a fdl-file (without "FDLVERSION1,") which before was created while connecting to wfs via **Add Interoperability Connection** manually.

As output I want to give a file-geodatabase which I think is causing the problem. It is created correctly, but maybe for the tool it must not exist anyway?

```c#
Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

ITrackCancel trac = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.CancelTracker();

string input = File.ReadAllText(fdlFile, Encoding.UTF8);
QuickImport import = new QuickImport();
import.Input = input.Replace("FDLVERSION1,", ""); ;
//import.Output = "C:/temp/wfs.gdb";

Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
IWorkspaceName wsn=workspaceFactory.Create("C:/temp", "wfs.gdb", null, 0);
import.Output = wsn;

try
{
    // error occurs here:
    object resi = gp.Execute(import, trac);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

Has anyone used this geoprocessing tool or has any idea?

---

I also tried it with `ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor2` - but same error:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor2 gp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessorClass();
gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

ITrackCancel trac = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.CancelTracker();

IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();

parameters.Add(@"WFS,https://www....");
parameters.Add("C:/temp/wfs.gdb");

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult resi = gp.Execute("QuickImport", parameters, trac);

if (resi.Status == esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
{ }
```

In the result-window of geoprocessing no new entry was created so I could not look to find the error.

---

If I remove the "@" in the line `parameters.Add(@"WFS,https://www....");`
the tool will be started and I see the entry in the results-window. But now the feature-dataset-list is empty. Their definition is in the fdl-file. So I have surely problems with the encoding of this file.

Comment: Reading [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-interoperability/using-the-quick-import-tool.htm) I would say the output geodatabase must not exist, you simply provide a string to a full path?

Comment: @Hornbydd I thought so and tried  `import.Output = "C:/temp/wfs.gdb"`, File doesn't exist but this worked not too.

Comment: Next thing I would try is to replace the input dataset with a local shapefile to help confirm that it is not a syntax error but an issue with it being a fws?

Comment: This doesn't work, because the output has to be a geodatabase, but I found out, problem comes with the first parameter (input dataset). If I only give it "WFS,url" then a toolprocess is started and will be shown in results window... see my next edit